# sign_in using Date(ex: birthday) with gem 'devise' rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

user will sign in using date(ex: birthday) with devise gem. I have tried this:

**user.rb** file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:account, :birthday]

  def email_required?
    false
  end
end
```

`users/sessions/new.html.erb` file:

```
   <%= f.date_select :birthday,  order: [:month, :day, :year]  %>
```

`application_controller.rb` file:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
      before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
      protected
      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:birthday, :account, :email, :password) }
      end
    end
```

what am i doing wrong??